# Apache crashing from django.contrib class WKBWriter/Reader

Tags: python, django, apache, django-contrib

I'm running a django application on an apache webserver. This application uses the django.contrib package, specifically django.contrib.gis.geos.

Now sometimes this works out well for weeks, only to come crashing down multiple times a day with seemingly no direct correlation to user interaction.

The log shows this:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/ptr.py", line 37, in __del__
NameError: name 'AttributeError' is not defined
[...] Exception ignored in: Exception ignored in: Exception ignored in: <bound method _WKBReader.__del__ of <django.contrib.gis.geos.prototypes.io._WKBReader object at 0x7ff4c2f92a58>>`

I have shortened the huge chain of `Exception ignored in:`s.
After this, apache won't serve any more requests until it is restarted but also still remain active as a daemon.

I am not sure which line exactly is responsible for this error. But I found this: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#creating-a-geometry
Under "My logs are filled with GEOS-related errors"
it says that this could be avoided by not having any GEOS-Objects created on top level, so I tried to purge those occurrences but it didn't help.
Also it seems weird to see `NameError: name 'AttributeError' is not defined` maybe that can hint to the root of this problem?

If you do not know how to instantly solve this, can you give me some insights on how to avoid it? 
Not using the package at all is possible but I really want to keep that as a last resort.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if you have solved this in the meantime. I have just encountered this exact error after updating from Django 2.x to 3.x. This might hold a clue.